# Output select to string using c++ connector

Tags: c++, mysql, select

How would I go about putting all the output from the while loop of a standard SELECT with the MySQL C++ connector into a string with delimiters to separate the output?
I am quite new to C++ and therefor have not learnt a lot yet about this.

I am currently using Visual Studio 2012 to code and compile my project.

Edit: this is what I've tried after Barmar's comment:

```
#include <vector>
vector<string> dbOutput;
while(res->next()){
dbOutput.push_back(res->getBlob("testcolumn"));
}
```

But I've gotten the error "No instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc>::push_back[with _Ty=std::string, _Alloc=std::allocator]" matches the argument list...".

Comment: Doesn't matter how new you are, you have to give it a try for us to help you. We don't just write code for you, we help you fix what you've tried.

Comment: I would but I am quite clueless on how to do this - C++ is a whole new way of coding for me, usually what I would do is put everything in an array and then use some function to convert it to a string with delimiters.

Comment: You can do that in C++. You can also use `std::vector` to simplify the array processing. But the overall approach is the same as in most other languages, just minor syntax differences. You're not going to learn unless you try.

Comment: Ah yes - `vector` does sound like the thing I want - I've just tried it out, but I get the error `No instance of overloaded function "....." matches the argument list` when I try `myVector.push_back(res->getBlob("testcolumn"));` I've declared the vector as follows: `vector<string> myVector;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`res->getBlob("testcolumn")` returns an object of type `std::istream*`, but `vector<string>::push_back()` only takes a string as parameter (as per `vector<string>` definition).

You need to extract the data from the `stream` into a `string`, then push this `string` into your `vector`. Eg:

```
vector<string> dbOutput;
std::istream *blob = res->getBlob("testcolumn");
std::string blobString = "";
std::string buffer;
while (!blob->eof()){
    *blob >> buffer;
    blobString += buffer;
}
dbOutput.push_back(blobString);
```

Comment: Thank you, this can get me started on the subject.